# Erro ao cadastrar dados no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

estou com uma dificuldade para inserir alguns dados no banco de dados. Na hora que clico em cadastrar aparece a mensagem no final do código de "erro ao cadastrar". Ja revisei o código e revirei o código quase por inteiro e nao consigo entrar uma solução, alguem pode me dar uma dica ?

```
 if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST ['cadastrar'] == "register")
```

{
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $rsenha = $_POST['rsenha'];

```
    if(empty($nome) || empty($sobrenome) || empty($data) || empty($cpf) || empty($email) ||  empty($pais) || empty($estado) || empty($login) || empty($senha) || empty($rsenha) || ($cpf_enviado == false) || (@$emailvalida == false))

  {

  }else{

            include_once("settings.php");
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_winfo");
            $query = "SELECT bd_winfo FROM cadastro WHERE login = '".$login."'";
            $cadastrar = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, data, cpf, email, pais, estado, login, senha, rsenha)
                    VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$data', '$cpf', '$email', '$pais', '$estado', '$login', '$senha', '$rsenha')";
                if(mysqli_query($con, $query))
                {
                  $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
                  $_SESSION['sobrenome'] = $sobrenome;
                  $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
                  $_SESSION['cpf'] = $cpf;
                  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                  $_SESSION['pais'] = $pais;
                  $_SESSION['estado'] = $estado;
                  $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                  $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;  
                  $_SESSION['rsenha'] = $rsenha;          

                }
                else
                {
                  echo '<div id="preencha" style="width:200px; position:relative; left:580px; top:-30px; color:#fff; font-size:15px; ">Erro ao cadastrar!</div>';
                }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Cara, dê um var_dump($cadastrar);exit(); e veja qual o retorno.

Comment: Pegue o resultado var_dump ou echo e coloque no Mysql para ver o que acontece, e ele irá te retornar o erro

Comment: Aviso:
O seu código ta com grande risco de ataques de Injection, use o PDO com o bindParam. Nunca concatene strings e execute SQL.

Comment: E se for usar variavel dentro da string tem que usar aspas duplas "$nome"